# Extract Table with structure maintained from PDF for feeding into LLM's

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model, cloud-document-ai, google-generativeai

I am trying to feed in LLM Model more specifically Vertex AI from Google a context from PDF. Generally GCP Document AI can do OCR to get text from the PDF, that text I pass on to LLM model as context along with my prompt. But issue is coming in case of Tables. Document AI or any open source PDF reader is not able to get Table as it is.

My table can have different alignments and formats for example:
[Sample image form PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRWXi.jpg)

Since header is center aligned Tabula-py didn't make them all in single row.

It is always true that I will get a Doc to PDF converted file only not a scanned image file.

Anyone can help in getting this solved.
Python based solution will be more apricated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the Document AI Form Parser processor?

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser

This processor can extract key-value pairs and tables from documents, which you can then structure the data into your prompt however works best for your use case.

Here's information on how the processing response is structured for Forms and Tables with code samples for printing out the data:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables